# Spacemacs evil-mode : How to toggle off visual mode in interactive function call?

Tags: spacemacs, evil, visual-line-mode

```
;; .spacemacs file
(defun my/function (beg end)
     ;; To work with visual selection:
     (interactive "r")

    ;; Displays visual selection in message buffer:
    (message (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end))

    ;; Now I want to toggle off visual selection in buffer
    ;; But I do not know how to do it?
)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way after exploring all `evil-` functions:

```
   (evil-normal-state 1)
```

My first idea was to use:

```
   (evil-visual-state -1)
```

But it leaves the buffer in `insert mode` with no possibility to go back to `normal mode`.

---

**Edit:** I have come to another way of doing it:

```
;; .spacemacs file
(defun my/function (beg end)
     ;; To work with visual selection:
     (interactive "r")

    ;; checking:   <-----------  section added
    (unless (evil-visual-state-p) (error "Not in visual mode..."))

    ;; Displays visual selection in message buffer:
    (message (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end))

    ;; Eventually the function I have been looking for:
    (evil-exit-visual-state)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for `evil-magit-maybe-deactivate-mark`

```
evil-magit-maybe-deactivate-mark is an interactive and compiled
function defined in evil-magit.el.

Documentation
Deactivate mark if region is active. Used for ESC binding.
```

Comment: I have stumbled upon this one. But I did not consider it as it seems to be useful in magit context only. Have you tested it?

Comment: I am using it already with some hydra-post-hook. It works everywhere and interactive function.

Comment: What do you think of `evil-exit-visual-state`?

Comment: I prefer still evil-magit... because it's more simple function if you see the function +
Just tested evil-exit visual state does not work if you are emacs-mode in spacemacs.